# Populate 3 columns in one panda dataframe using lookup values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_source, and df_dest as follows:

```
>>> df_source = pd.read_csv('Product_Lookup.csv')
>>> df_source
   ProdCode    ProdName        ProdUPC  ProdQty
0       131       Apple  1100034030045        1
1       320   Bookshelf  2222200209090        1
2       420  Comic Book  4449435895489        5
3       511   Drillbits  5558493958393       10
4        55        Eggs  6660001110005       20
5        12   Fish food  9099910002776       50

>>> df_dest = pd.read_csv('Product_Dest.csv')
>>> df_dest
  CustName  ProdCode  ProdName  ProdUPC  ProdQty
0     Fred        12       nan      nan      nan
1   Sanjay       131       nan      nan      nan
2     Rita       55        nan      nan      nan
3    Steph       511       nan      nan      nan
4   Hannah        55       nan      nan      nan
5    Roger       131       nan      nan      nan
```

I've not seen a question here yet for pandas that handles multi-column population in a lookup function.

I am trying to populate `df_dest.loc[:,['ProdName','ProdUPC','ProdQty']]` by matching `df_dest['ProdCode']` with `df_source['ProdCode']`.

I could do it with `iterrows()`, but hoping for something faster and a little more elegant. Any help super appreciated!

Comment: Do you want `df = df_dest.merge(df_source, on='ProdCode')`  ?

Comment: Thanks. I searched for a couple of hours, but was not using the right terms required to find the appropriate solution.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely understand you. You are welcome!